# Merge multiple datatables into one

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I have multiple (15) datatables and I want to merge into one.

Commonly I used 'merge' to merge datatables, but output showing like this:

[image]

Required output is this:

[image]

Comment: maybe you can show us this `i used 'merge' to merge datatables` query

Comment: Why you tag it to sql and sq-server?

Comment: This is not a free code-writing service nor a do-my-job-for-me service. Someone with 3 yrs experience should be able to write/overload the merge method to do whatever it is you desire. You will find that writing a generic version of this might be difficult since the logic needs to know which column/columns are the keys to associating rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below using aggregation and  group by

```
select srno, max(cpe) as cpe, max(cpo) as cpo, max(cpc) as cpc
from tablename
group by srno
```

Comment: I WANT TO MERGE C# DATATABLE IN C#

Answer (score 0):

You can set full outer join and can fetch data like you want.

```
Select 
CPC.Id,
CPC.CPC,
CPO.CPO,
CPE.CPE
from CPC
FULL OUTER JOIN CPO on CPO.Id = CPC.Id
FULL OUTER JOIN CPE on CPE.Id = CPC.Id
```

so by using this I have get exactly same output as per your expectation. So you can try it like this.

Comment: I WANT TO MERGE C# DATATABLE IN C#

Comment: shouting ALWAYS helps!